# Discover system dependencies for a workspace

Tags: rosdep, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a clever way to recover all *system* dependencies for the set of packages in a *workspace*?  Something like `rosdep resolve`, but that works on ROS packages in a catkin workspace?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280309/discover-system-dependencies-for-a-workspace/) by [ivaughn](https://answers.ros.org/users/32451/ivaughn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2018-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-19**:
On a clean system `rosdep check --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src` would show this. But not on a system that has everything already installed unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the simulate option to rosdep install.

See for a full answer.
https://answers.ros.org/question/251732/how-can-generate-a-list-of-dependencies-from-the-src-folder-of-a-workspace/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1